# Place a dialog on top of another div

Tags: html, css

I need to place a dialog(with `position:fixed` to keep it fixed while scrolling page) exactly on top of another div in page body. I have centered layout on my page so I cannot figure out how can I set the `left` property in CSS for the dialog. For the `top` property I know the value as this dialog is kept below nav bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nice question.

it has 2 answers :

1) use javascript to determine the sizes...

2) without js - its a pure html trick :
http://css-tricks.com/320-quick-css-trick-how-to-center-an-object-exactly-in-the-center/